# How to compare the columns of file1 to the columns of file2, select matching values, and output to new file using grep or unix commands

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, grep

I have two files, file1 and file2, where the target_id compose the first column in both.

I want to compare file1 **to** file2, and **only keep the rows** of file1 which match the target_id in file2.

[image: file1]

**file2:**

```
target_id
ENSMUST00000128641.2
ENSMUST00000185334.7
ENSMUST00000170213.2
ENSMUST00000232944.2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

`% grep -x -f file1 file2`  resulted in no output in my terminal

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please replace image with its text.

Comment: Stacks' tag recommendation engine is imperfect, please pay attention to the tags that are suggested. The easiest way (perhaps after you actually submit the question) is to mouse-over each one and read what they have to say; while many have no description, the [tag:r] tag here should have been a clear "not related".

Comment: @Cyrus and r2evans Thank you both very much! I'm new to stack, and I will make sure to format my posts correctly and tag them correctly.

Comment: Please replace image with its text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data that actually shows overlaps between the files.

- `file1.csv`:

  ```
  target_id,KO_1D_7dpi,KO_2D_7dpi
  ENSMUST00000178537.2,0,0
  ENSMUST00000178862.2,0,0
  ENSMUST00000196221.2,0,0
  ENSMUST00000179664.2,0,0
  ENSMUST00000177564.2,0,0
  ```
- `file2.csv`

  ```
  target_id
  ENSMUST00000178537.2
  ENSMUST00000196221.2
  ENSMUST00000177564.2
  ```

Your `grep` command, but swapped:

```bash
$ grep -F -f file2.csv file1.csv
target_id,KO_1D_7dpi,KO_2D_7dpi
ENSMUST00000178537.2,0,0
ENSMUST00000196221.2,0,0
ENSMUST00000177564.2,0,0
```

*Edit*: we can add the `-F` argument since it is a fixed-string search. Plus it adds protection against the `.` matching something else as a regex. Thanks to @Sundeep for the recommendation.

Comment: Would recommend adding `-F` option since regex isn't required (will be faster and `.` will be matched literally)

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, indeed safer (and faster with larger datasets).