# How to remove values in a text file from another text file in R?

Tags: r, text-files

I have a file that contains a list (n = 83)

```
rs997007
rs66492148
1:18293758
rs4920291
rs223177
```

I have another file that contains a list (n = 5777).

```
rs997007
rs66492148
rs72648488
1:18293758
rs71579813
rs4920291
rs223177
rs72650382
```

Everything in file 1, I want removed from file 2. So file 2 looks like this
(n = 5694):

```
rs72648488
rs71579813
rs72650382
```

I have no idea what R function to use when handling text files?

Comment: `setdiff(file2, file1)`

Comment: `setdiff()` will also remove duplicate values from `file2` though, using `%in%` would be more conservative

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74607019/3358272, you can use the command-line (not  R function) utility `grep` and the `-F -f filename` as a list of "patterns", and optional use of `-v` to invert (non-matching). This is all assuming that when you say "file", you mean a text file on your local filesystem, not an object in R.

Comment: You can use `grep -v -F -f file1.txt file2.txt` to get your intended output.